# Where to configure applications that appears in account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com portal

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have created my custom AAD in Azure Portal and I have registered my web app, so that I can use AAD Authentication in the app.

What needs to be done in order to display the app in https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/ portal in the Applications section?

Answer (score -1):

You can manage the apps permissions here.
https://portal.azure.com - Azure Active Directory - Enterprise Applications - All Applications
https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/StartboardApplicationsMenuBlade/AllApps/menuId/

Thanks,
prathaprabhu
COSMICOMPUTERS
Microsoft Partner

Comment: it doesn't answer my question. I haven't asked about app permissions.